# how to redirect_back to another subdmain with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am using devise  to handle registration and authentication.

My entire application is divided into 2 sub-domains. `secure.host.dev` and `main.host.dev`.

When user visit `http://main.host.dev/users`, if not authenticated, must be redirected to `http://secure.host.dev/host`. This is working perfectly.

The problem is with the redirect back after login. It should redirect_back to `http://main.host.dev/users` and not to `http://secure.host.dev/users` as it is now.

How can do that? I did not find any documentation about this

Comment: try it with `:subdomain => false`

Comment: @pitabasprathal where I have to put this code?

Comment: Have you tried to use this code in application controller? 

`def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
     some_path
   end`

Comment: I modified my answer

Comment: @jgrant the problem is not redirect to static resource. But the the previous one. This code will always redirect user to `articles_path`.

Comment: you would put your specified path in the articles_path part.  e.g. whatever helper you are using for http://main.host.dev/users

Comment: @jgrant that is the problem. I dont want to use a specific path as I dont know from where users come from. I use `users_path` as an example. IT could be `articles_path` or other.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105396/discussion-between-jgrant-and-psantos).

Comment: You can go to devise's Github and copy their Session Controller into your app so that it loads this version instead of the default. Then customize your version however you need.

Comment: creating from scratch the authentication layer as I want was more easy and fast than using `Devise`